# Adding multiple points to a ggplot ecdf plot

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, ggplot2, statistics

I'm trying to generate a ggplot only C.D.F. plot for some of my data. I am also looking to be able to plot an arbitrary number of percentiles as points on top. I have a solution that works for adding a single point to my curve but fails for multiple values.

This works for plotting one percentile value

```
TestDf <- as.data.frame(rnorm(1000))
names(TestDf) <- c("Values")
percentiles <- c(0.5)

ggplot(data = TestDf, aes(x = Values)) +
  stat_ecdf() +
  geom_point(aes(x = quantile(TestDf$Values, percentiles),
                 y = percentiles))
```

[image: Here is the output]

However this fails

```
TestDf <- as.data.frame(rnorm(1000))
names(TestDf) <- c("Values")
percentiles <- c(0.25,0.5,0.75)

ggplot(data = TestDf, aes(x = Values)) +
  stat_ecdf() +
  geom_point(aes(x = quantile(TestDf$Values, percentiles),
                 y = percentiles))
```

With error

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (1000): x, y

How can I add an arbitrary number of points to a `stat_ecdf()` plot?

Comment: `ggplot(data = TestDf, aes(x = Values)) +
  stat_ecdf() +
    geom_point(data = data.frame(x=quantile(TestDf$Values, percentiles),
                  y=percentiles), aes(x=x, y=y))`

Comment: Hi @Masoud, this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a new dataset, outside of the aesthetics. `aes` refers to the original dataframe that you used for making the CDF (in the original `ggplot` argument).

```
ggplot(data = TestDf, aes(x = Values)) +
  stat_ecdf() +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x=quantile(TestDf$Values, percentiles),
              y=percentiles), aes(x=x, y=y))
```

[image]